# Play framework event on Model delete

Tags: events, playframework

I am using Play framework 1.2.6. I am trying to get a Event or Listen some event if in my application any model call the delete or add. i.e. if deletion of data or addition happens in database through Model, then is there any way to get a event for this.

Please let me know if I am not very clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the **@PreRemove** annotation on your model method.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/cheatsheet/model

Answer (score 0):

You can override the _save() and _delete() methods in your model.

```
@Override
public void _delete() {
   // .. do something
   super._delete();
}

@Override
public void _save() {
   // .. do something
   super._save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not what I want, I know this is a way but I have many models I do not want to do this everywhere. I just need a event like Spring AOP. But anyway thanks.